# Datepicker (matCalendar) angular2 should move when scrolling page

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using a datepicker, when i click on datepicker the calendar opens, Now I need is that when I scroll the page the calendar should move along the page can some one suggest me how to do this. I am new to angular2.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your calendar in a `div` and give it a [position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) `fixed` attribute.

```
<div class="test">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

---

```
.test {
  position: fixed;
}
```

---

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srvkgm)